# File restriction to specific page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make a file only accessible when you're on a specific page. 
Like download.php, the user can click a link to the file and the download starts  without problems.

But if you go to the link in the browser directly it should not work.

Could I use `.htaccess` for this? or how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with `.htaccess` by checking for the `${HTTP_REFERER}`, which is the previous url you were on.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.example.com/download.php
RewriteRule myFile.zip - [R=403,L]
```

This checks if the previous page was `download.php`, otherwise it rewrites the request for myFile.zip to a 403 error page.

Note that it is possible to forge a referer by intercepting / creating your own request. This does not provide 100% security.

Comment: Close enough.. Thanks. Btw.. htaccess is so confusing :-/